# Is there an AI-powered tool that will act as a code-reviewer on Gitlab in the form of comments and suggestions?

Tags: git, artificial-intelligence, github

Does anyone know about an **AI-powered tool that will act as a code-reviewer** in git tools like gitlab or github and automatically analyze the merge-request changes and give feedback (at least for obvious mistakes) to the developer, in the format of a code review?

**Functionality**

- Provide **feedback to the MR author** on obvious improvements or potential bugs, excl. linting (we have CI/CD for that)
- Give **recommendations in terms of "better" code** for certain parts
- Potentially base these recommendations on the task description in the merge request

That would save time for me as a lead developer leading 8 developers, as I would not need to review the "obvious" stuff, especially when working with many junior devs.

Comment: Hello, I hope you're not talking about it as a replacement of CR rather than an addition to it, but the last sentence unfortunately suggests the 1st. Each software is different and AI doesn't luckily (yet) have godly capabilities of knowing good practices in specific projects and especially not what could be considered as a bug, else a lot of programmers, definitely your juniors, could be replaced.

Comment: Yeah no defenetly not a replacement for me. But there could be things like: This is just a really messy function. That function could be split up. That naming is a bit weird. Did you forget to handle an error here? Stuff like that I don't need to look at, or at least I don't want to look at. It's unnecessary. I will look at architecture, general decisions being made, relationships to other MRs. When I paste my files into chatGPT it can give me such recommendations already.

Comment: That's a job for code/style analyzers, not AI, then. They exist for majority of popular languages and  can check for things such as too long functions, errors or various naming conventions. E.g. phpstan and php-cs-fixer for PHP.

Comment: Github has apparently  announced that their CoPilot Chatbot will be soon be available in the User Interface of the Github.com web site. (Unlike the "usual"  IDE Extension, on local dev workstations). Maybe review  Public Relations material released during the  "Github Universe" conference, Nov 2023. Perhaps there will be a waitlist for that upcoming variant of the copilor chatbot.

Answer (score 1):

Now that more and more tools get developed, there is a few, most only support Github but I found two that support Gitlab:

- [coderabbit.ai](https://coderabbit.ai)
- [Codium.ai pr-agent](https://github.com/Codium-ai/pr-agent)